# Data reading in R

Tags: r

I am trying to read a excel file in R. But it gives some errors. How can I read the data for further programming. I used the below line:

```
library(xlsx)
d <- read.xlsx("E:/MajorProject/DataSet/pimaxl.xls", sheetName = pimaxl)
```

Anybody please help me.

Comment: Could you please post what error you get?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the error you are getting. That being said: I sometimes had to use ` read.xlsx2("Book1.xls", sheetIndex = 1, header = TRUE)` to read some `xls` files (although I did never get an error but just an empty return value)

Answer (score -1):

You are using 'read.xlsx' to read a '.xls' file. Either save your file in the '.xlsx' format or use a different function to read the file. e.g https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/readxl/versions/0.1.1/topics/read_excel

Comment: The question is not about the `readxl` , but about the `xlsx` package!

Comment: But your answer is wrong. `xlsx::read.xlsx` is perfectly capable of reading `xls` files. Did you test it? Giving false information and just suggesting other packages is not helping...